# ad5359 address not shown

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi, i2c, addressing

I am working AD5259 , its a digital potentiometer.

Its connected to i2c bus on raspberry pi.
But the address of device is not shown. Datasheets says its 0X18.

I guess the device does not respond to general call.

I am kind of stuck on this , any help will be apprecaited.

Comment: "the address of device is not shown" - Who does not "show the address"?

Comment: Did you try reading/writing using address 0x18?  The datasheet does not say anything about a general call address.  Also, note that it says "I2C-compatible", not "I2C-compliant", so some I2C features may be missing.

Comment: Is that a 7 bit or 8 bit address?  If it is a 7-bit address, so you have to shift the bits over 1 bit to get the value put into the address byte sent to the device: 00110000 (0x30) for writing and 00110001 (0x31) for reading.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
The pins AD0 and AD1 on AD5259 needs to be grounded.
I was missing that part . so i can see it at address 0x18 now.

Thanks all for your help.